# Allow express-session to work properly in an iframe

Tags: node.js, express, iframe, express-session

Okay, simple problem, but I have no idea about how to approach it. I have an iframe that runs a server that uses express-session. However, the "connect.sid" cookie cannot save because the iframe and the parent site are cross-site. I would still like to use express-session in my iframe to save cookie data, but I cannot figure out how to go about doing that.

TL;DR
Basically, I want an iframe to be able to use cookies.

Comment: I too have this question!